# RHN Clients Transaction Error Oracle Linux 6.1 Server to Desktop

Tags: yum, oracle-linux

I have inherited a vm with 6.1 oracle linux server install on it. I don't have a linux background, so mostly I have been googling answers. The first hurdle was to get network working. Next I was going to try and get the desktop gui working. [I found instructions here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2556908).

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System" Desktop "General Purpose Desktop" \ 
"Graphical Administration Tools" "Legacy X Window System compatibility" \
system-config-lvm
```

However I am getting a known error, but haven't been able to get past it.

```
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E57668/html/section_gxm_115_wp.html
```

I found directions on a foreign site, but still having issues.

```
http://nosmoking.blog.51cto.com/3263888/1672607
```

What exactly do I need to do? I've attached a picture of the current error that I am getting and the results of some commands on one of the sites above.
[image: Error message.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum install oraclelinux-release
yum install rhn-client-tools
```

After these two were installed independently, it let me proceed with the desktop install. So this is done now.